# How to get the list of installed/non-installed dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I am currently using some libraries (e.b. material design lib) to create apps.
I want to set the minimum SDK to 5.0, but it cannot be done because the version of that library is higher.

My question is how can I know the list of installed/non-installed dependencies(e.g. com.android.support:design) provided by Google in android studio(like SDK manager) or not?

Honestly, I was using the Eclipse IDE for developing android apps, and now I switch to Android Studio. It is difficult to me to use Android Studio. Is there any resources to learn more detailed about the usage of Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is how can I know the list of installed/non-installed
>   dependencies provided by Google in android studio(like SDK manager) or
>   not?

At first make sure in the left panel `Project` is selected.

[image]

Then right-click on your appropriate project name and select `Open Module Settings`

[image]

There you will see the `Dependencies` tab that you were searching for. There you will explore the options to add or remove dependencies or shifting them up or down in the easiest way. Hope you will find Android Studio more interesting then Eclipse gradually.

> Is there any resources to learn more detailed about the usage of
>   Android Studio?

The official android developer site of Google is well enough to learn Android Studio in details. Everything is there. Still you can also go for *tutorialspoint* tutorial about Android Studio.

**Links:**

https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_studio.htm

Comment: Thanks for the help. I searched that there are many versions of material design/support libs  but I can't see in SDK manager.  where can I find them?

Comment: I know you gave me instruction of opening SDK manager. But I dont see the "com.android.support:"(e.g. design, appcompat, etc.) libraries' versions in SDK manager. Now I type "compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'" in app.module to use those libraries. I want to use lower version of design library but I can't do that.

Comment: Thanks. I just searched that there are lots of versions of support libraries, and I want to know which one I can use.  I have no idea where to see those versions in Android Studio.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer. Please now look at the answer if it helps.

Comment: Another question: I can only see the currently version is 25. Can I get version that is lower than 25, e.g. 22? I dont see any lower version. I want to build lower API level app in order to increase Device Compatibility.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?? As far as you have chosen 25, then it will support all lower versions automatically.